# Can we automate extrinsic calls in Substrate chain?

Tags: substrate-node, parathread, coretime

Recently I tested agile core time feature on Rococo. The idea was to test Parathread producing block.

We have to submit either `placeOrderAllowDeath` or `placeOrderKeepAlive` extrinsic from `onDemandAssignmentProvider`. Once we submit this extrinsic and the collator is working, a new parachain block should be included within a few relay chain blocks depending on congestion.

I tested it and it's working. I was just wondering if there is any way to automate this process so that I don't need to submit same extrinsic multiple times in order to produce block.

Please help me to provide the solution.